# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (100) . The gpu is enabled but still giving error

Tags: pytorch, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am new to google Colab and pyTorch. I am running a pytorch model but it is giving me the **Cuda Runtime Error** in google Colab. My gpu is enabled on google colab but it is still giving error, The description of gpu is available in the image below. Can anyone please help me out?

[**torch GPU**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfCnL.png)

```
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=47 error=100 : no CUDA-capable device is detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 338, in <module>
    main()
  File "run.py", line 303, in main
    model = model.cuda()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 458, in cuda
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 354, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 354, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 354, in _apply
    module._apply(fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 376, in _apply
    param_applied = fn(param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 458, in <lambda>
    return self._apply(lambda t: t.cuda(device))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 190, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (100) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /pytorch/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:47
Read prediction from logs/logs_sparc_editsql/valid_use_predicted_queries_predictions.json
```

Comment: What GPU is installed in the system? What CUDA version is installed? Are any GPUs in the system ignored due to environment variable `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`?

Comment: @njuffa I am using google colab **https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfCnL.png** . This is the specs of gpu. Also when I am training other pytorch model it is working on the same GPU.

Comment: @njuffa Version ```nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:07:16_PDT_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243``` Also how to know if gpu is ignored?

Answer (score -1):

Nvm, I was putting `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to **5**.
It should be the number of CUDA devices you have.